# Mapping an attribute of a nested structure

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a nested structure of network interfaces.

```
interfaces:
  - name: bond0
    bonding_xmit_hash_policy: layer3+4
    bridge:
      name: br0
      inet: 12.34.56.78/24
    slaves:
      - name: eth0
        mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
      - name: eth1
        mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
      - name: eth2
        mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
      - name: eth3
        mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

I now want to generate a flat list of all defined interface *names*:

- bond0
- br0
- eth0
- eth1
- eth2
- eth3

In theory this should be simple but I fail to extract the names of of the slave interfaces (`eth0` - `eth3`)

Here are the working parts:

1. List of interfaces on the root level (`bond0` in this example)

   ```
   interfaces | map(attribute='name') | list
   ```
2. List of bridge interfaces

   ```
   interfaces | selectattr('bridge', 'mapping') | map(attribute='bridge') | map(attribute='name') | list
   ```

Here is my attempt to get all the slave interface names:

```
interfaces | selectattr('slaves') | map(attribute='slaves') | map(attribute='name') | list
```

In words, first reduce the list of interfaces and only get those interfaces which have a `slaves` attribute. Then with the `map` filter get the slaves. Until here it works and if I output the result it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", 
        "name": "eth0"
    }, 
    {
        "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", 
        "name": "eth1"
    }, 
    {
        "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", 
        "name": "eth2"
    }, 
    {
        "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", 
        "name": "eth3"
    }
]
```

This clearly is a list of objects. And this is actually the same format as the interfaces on the root level of the structure (`bond0`). But when I try to again get the `name` attribute of all objects with `map` it will fail, the result is `[Undefined]`. (Note the `[]`. It seems to be a list of Undefined, not simply undefined)

But this is exactly what the [map](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) filter should do:

> Applies a filter on a sequence of objects or looks up an attribute. This is useful when dealing with lists of objects but you are really only interested in a certain value of it.
>
> The basic usage is mapping on an attribute. Imagine you have a list of users but you are only interested in a list of usernames

For testing purpose I also tried to see what happens when I use `selectattr`:

```
interfaces | selectattr('slaves') | map(attribute='slaves') | selectattr('name') | list
```

This should make no difference since all objects do have a `name` property, but Ansible is failing with:

> FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! 'list object' has no attribute 'name'"}

Somehow it appears there is a list inside the list, which is not shown by the debug task since the output appears to be a list of objects but from point of view of Jinja it appears it is working with a list of lists?

Has anyone an idea what is going on and how to simply get the interface names out of that list?

For now I solved this with a custom filter plugin but I don't understand why this does not work right out of the box. If this stays unsolved and anyone comes across the same issue, here is my plugin:

```
class FilterModule(object):
    
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'interfaces_flattened': self.interfaces_flattened
        }
    def interfaces_flattened(*args):
        names = []
        for interface in args[1]:
            names.extend(get_names(interface))
        return names

def get_names(interface):
    names = []
    if "name" in interface:
        names.append(interface["name"])
    if "bridge" in interface:
        names.append(interface["bridge"]["name"])
    if "slaves" in interface:
        for slave in interface["slaves"]:
            names.extend(get_names(slave))
    return names
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"Flat list of all defined interface names."***

A: There are more options.

- Use the filter *json_query*. For example,

```yaml
  names: "{{ interfaces|
             json_query('[].[name, *.name, *[].name]')|
             flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  names: [bond0, br0, eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3]
```

- The iteration

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        names: "{{ names|d([]) + [item.split(':')|last|trim] }}"
      loop: "{{ (interfaces|to_nice_yaml).splitlines() }}"
      when: item is match('^.*\\s+name:\\s+.*$')
```

gives

```yaml
  names: [br0, bond0, eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    interfaces:
      - name: bond0
        bonding_xmit_hash_policy: layer3+4
        bridge:
          name: br0
          inet: 12.34.56.78/24
        slaves:
          - name: eth0
            mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          - name: eth1
            mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          - name: eth2
            mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          - name: eth3
            mac: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

    names: "{{ interfaces|
               json_query('[].[name, *[].name]')|
               flatten }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: names|to_yaml

    - set_fact:
        names: "{{ names + [item.split(':')|last|trim] }}"
      loop: "{{ (interfaces|to_nice_yaml).splitlines() }}"
      when: item is match('^.*\\s+name:\\s+.*$')
      vars:
        names: []
    - debug:
        var: names|to_yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

**For those who are interested in no loop solution**
one of possible solutions to all this is:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    all_names: "{{ a+b+c }}"
  vars:
    a: "{{ interfaces | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
    b: "{{ interfaces | map(attribute='bridge.name') | list }}"
    c: "{{ interfaces | map(attribute='slaves') | flatten | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
```

returns:

```json
        "all_names": [
            "bond0",
            "br0",
            "eth0",
            "eth1",
            "eth2",
            "eth3"
        ]
```

**Explanation**

In

```
interfaces | selectattr('slaves') | map(attribute='slaves') | map(attribute='name') | list
```

you don't need the

```
selectattr('slaves')
```

the list interfaces has only 1 dict that has "slaves" and selectattr returns the that 1 dict.

with map its the same story, you are still mapping a list with 1 item and looking for attribute slaves, difference is that it returns only that attribute of the dict.

```
interfaces | map(attribute='slaves') | list
```

returns:

```json
[
    [
        {
            "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
            "name": "eth0"
        },
        {
            "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
            "name": "eth1"
        },
        {
            "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
            "name": "eth2"
        },
        {
            "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
            "name": "eth3"
        }
    ]
]
```

use

```
| flatten
```

on this list to get only the list that you want, then you can use map(attribute="name") on the following list to get the names.

*edited for clarity.*

Comment: I really like this answer. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, not really DRY, but perhaps a bit more readable.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    first_list: "{{ item.slaves | map(attribute='name') }}"
  loop: "{{ interfaces }}"

- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ 
          first_list + 
          interfaces | map(attribute='name') +
          interfaces | map(attribute='bridge.name') 
      }}
```